# Antijoin with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem optimizing a query with postgresql 10.4

for example, when I run

> select * from t1 where i not in (select j from t2)

I expect pg to use the index on t2.j, but it does not. Here is the plan that I get :

```
Seq Scan on t1  (cost=169.99..339.99 rows=5000 width=4)
  Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..144.99 rows=9999 width=4)
```

Is pg not able to use indexs for antijoin or is there something obvious that I miss ?

The SQL that I used to create the tables :

```
create table t1(i integer);
insert into t1(i) select s from generate_series(1, 10000) s;
create table t2(j integer);
insert into t2(j) select s from generate_series(1, 9999) s;
create index index_j on t2(j);
```

I have a similar problem with tables over 1 million rows, and using table scans just to fetch a few fundreed records is very slow...

thanks,

Comment: Try using `t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.i = t2.j WHERE t2.field IS NULL` in place of `WHERE i NOT IN ...`

Comment: indeed it looks better !

Comment: "using table scans just to fetch a few fundreed records is very slow..."  Not as slow as using several thousand index scans to fetch just 1 (qualifying) record.